# collect2 error while compiling fortran code

Tags: compiling, fortran

I have installed `necdf-4` successfully. I am getting

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

error when I compile a fortran code that writes `netcdf` files. I use `gfortran compiler`. 
I am sure the code is bug free.

What could be the reason for the problem? 
Please suggest a solution.

Comment: [Old Fortran Program: ld returned 1 exit status](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18155442/old-fortran-program-ld-returned-1-exit-status): Are Windows compatible line endings in the code causing the problem?

Comment: I am using simple_xy_wr.f90 code given in: http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/examples/programs/ site. The issue is resolved now. Answer is given below.

Comment: I linked the libraries and included the netcdf.mod file and then compiled as given below:

"gfortran  -o xy -I/home/dd/local/include/ simple_xy_wr.f90 -L/home/dd/local/lib/  -lnetcdf". 

I get the following output:
 *** SUCCESS writing example file simple_xy.nc!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I linked the libraries and included the netcdf.mod file and then compiled as given below:

```
gfortran  -o xy -I/home/dd/local/include/ simple_xy_wr.f90 -L/home/dd/local/lib/  -lnetcdf
```

I get the following output:

```
SUCCESS writing example file simple_xy.nc!
```